# How to implement ERC721Receiver with vyper v0.3.3

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, nft, contract-debugging, vyper

I am trying to implement a function, `onERC721Received`, using Vyper v0.3.3, that is called when an NFT is transferred to the contract using `safeTransferFrom`. According to the [this](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/master/examples/tokens/ERC721.vy#L278) ERC721 token standard, `safeTransferFrom` expects the return value to be of type `bytes4`, but in Vyper 0.3.3 I cannot compile the following code:

```
@external
def onERC721Received(_operator: address,_from: address,_tokenId: uint256,_data: Bytes[1024]) -> bytes4:
    return method_id("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)", output_type=bytes4)
```

It produces the following error message:

`vyper.exceptions.ArgumentException: output_type must be bytes[4] or bytes32`

So when I change `bytes4` to `Bytes[4]`, as in the code below, the code compiles, but when I try to call `safeTransferFrom` to transfer an NFT to the contract, the transaction reverts.

```
@external
def onERC721Received(_operator: address,_from: address,_tokenId: uint256,_data: Bytes[1024]) -> Bytes[4]:
    return method_id("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)", output_type=Bytes[4])
```

**How can I implement `onERC721Received` correctly so that it returns the correct value to `safeTransferFrom` on the ERC721 token standard cited above?**

Comment: The output_type was modified in master branch after the release of 0.3.3, see the PR https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/issues/2811. You could use vyper from master branch, or use the old [ERC721.vy](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/54b94d3233f795ef65687216322b427365b5c766/examples/tokens/ERC721.vy#L283).